# jQuery: Why use document.ready if external JS at bottom of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am including all of my JS as external files that are loaded at the very bottom of the page. Within these files, I have several methods defined like so, which I call from the ready event:

```
var SomeNamepsace = {};

SomeNamepsace.firstMethod = function () {
    // do something
};

SomeNamepsace.secondMethod = function () {
    // do something else
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    SomeNamepsace.firstMethod();
    SomeNamepsace.secondMethod();
});
```

However, when I remove the ready function and call the methods straight-up, everything works just the same, but executes significantly faster—almost a whole second faster on a pretty basic file! Since the document should be loaded at this point (as all the markup comes before the script tags), is there any good reason to still be using the ready event?

Comment: Interesting question. Sadly the current answers don't really answer the question and I don't have any good answers either. Maybe it would help to rephrase the question as: "is putting JavaScript documents at the end of the file guarantee the DOM is loaded before execution"

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Great question.

There is some confusion around the whole "put scripts at the bottom of your page" advice and what problem(s) it attempts to solve. For this question I am not going to talk about whether putting scripts at the bottom of the page affects performance/loadtimes or not. I am only going to talk about whether you need `$(document).ready` *if you also put scripts at the bottom of the page*.

I'm assuming you are referencing the DOM in those functions you are immediately invoking in your scripts (anything as simple as `document` or `document.getElementById`). I'm also assuming you are asking only about these [DOM-referencing] files. IOW, library scripts or scripts that your DOM-referencing code requires (like jQuery) need to be placed earlier in the page.

**To answer your question**: if you include your DOM-referencing scripts at the bottom of the page, No, you do not need `$(document).ready`.

**Explanation**: *without* the aid of `"onload"`-related implementations like `$(document).ready` the rule of thumb is: any code that interacts with DOM elements within the page should to be placed/included further down the page than the elements it references. The easiest thing to do is to place that code before the closing `</body>`. See [here](http://javascriptant.com/articles/10/qa-on-javascript-execution-onload-techniques) and [here](http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/exeorder.htm). It also works around IE's dreaded ["Operation aborted" error](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/04/23/what-happened-to-operation-aborted.aspx).

Having said that, this by no means invalidates the use of `$(document).ready`. Referencing an object before it has been loaded is [one of] the most common mistakes made when beginning in DOM JavaScript (witnessed it too many times to count). It is jQuery's solution to the problem, and it doesn't require you to have to think about where this script will be included relative to the DOM elements it references. This is a huge win for developers. It's just one less thing they have to think about.

Also, it's often difficult or impractical to move all DOM-referencing scripts to the bottom of the page (for example any script that issues `document.write` calls have to stay put). Other times, you are using a framework that renders some template or creates pieces of dynamic javascript, within which references functions that need to be included *before* the js.

Finally, it used to be "best practice" to jam all DOM-referencing code into `window.onload`, however it has been eclipsed by `$(document).ready` implementations for [well document reasons](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/09/busted/).

All this adds up to `$(document).ready` as a far superior, practical and general solution to the problem of referencing DOM elements too early.

Comment: "if you include your DOM-referencing scripts at the bottom of the page, No, you do not need $(document).ready. " Ignoring the document.write issue you address later in your post, this answer makes the naive assumption that all CSS is downloaded and processed prior to the javascript being run.  This may not be true; browsers can download external files in parallel.

Comment: not entirely correct, if you have any `defer` scripts document ready will ensure they execute prior to the ready code. see: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-end.html#the-end