# Keyup doesn't respond

Tags: jquery

I don't know what the hell is going on.

Why isn't my simple javascript code working? Been here for hours. I have a bunch of other javascript, was thinking if it's interrupting or something?

Trying to through a tutorial, then I got stuck at the first line:

```
$('#name').keyup(function() {
    alert('alert');
});
```

I don't know the problem.. in fiddle it's all working of course
http://jsfiddle.net/pgWtK/1/

I tried putting it inside the head with document ready but that doesn't help so, any clues?

Comment: Can you post your complete code?

Comment: sure. Jquery is now running inside the document ready function and it's still the same result (see vote.js). I can post the page I am trying to get it work in. [link](http://epicesports.com/vote/) .I am so thankful that you guys posted so many guidelines for me.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open but I want you to append links and whatnot to the question if you would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the file vote.js
change the code wth this code you have miss `$(`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(function(){
     $('#name').keyup(function() {
     alert('alert');
     });
  });
})
```

Comment: Okay BIG thanks to you and everyone! I am so stupid! This with combination with document ready made everything work as it should. Thank you again and sorry for my bad skill.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `put it in $(document).ready(function(){` so that the DOM elements are available to jquery before use, in your case element with id name for binding keyup event.

`Also make sure you have included jquery tag.` This **[article](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)** will guide you how to use jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
     $('#name').keyup(function() {
        alert('alert');
     });
})
```

Comment: you forgot to wrap the `document` inside the jQuery, `$(document).ready();`, P.S. the DV is not from me

Comment: Thanks @3nigma, so nice of you.

Comment: I have not tried yet to include the jquery tag, I will try this.

Comment: You should, That could be the reason. include before you use jquery

Answer (score 2):

Two things might happen, you dont have correctly loaded Jquery Library or you have not putted that code inside document ready

add jquery in your head example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jquery inside `document ready`

```
$(function(){
   $('#name').keyup(function() {
      alert('alert');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure FireBug or an alternative is installed
2. Check jQuery is loading in the Network panel of FireBug or alternative. If you're loading from a cdn and testing locally, make sure there's a fallback if it's not loading
3. Make sure your jQuery code is wrapped in a `$(document).ready(...)` call
4. Use the following code in your console of FiregBug or alternative to make sure that the event has been bound to the element:

   $('#name').data('events');

Answer (score 0):

wrap up your code inside the document ready

```
$(function(){
 //your code

});
```

in jsfiddle it done by default but if you select the `no-wrap(head)` option it would not wrap your js code inside the `ready` handler [see it for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/pgWtK/2/).

[It's always a good practice to place your js code inside the `ready` handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438883/jquery-why-use-document-ready-if-external-js-at-bottom-of-page) so that it is ensured before all the js glitter happens the DOM is rendered, or you can place the js script at the end of your markup