# jQuery toggle clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I am trying to make an app in which when you click some text it shows content and when you click again it hides it.
my current jquery is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$("h2").toggle( 
    function(){ $(this).next().show(); },
    function(){ $(this).next().hide(); }
    ); //end of toggle

}); // end of ready
```

but when I run it on browser everything hides immediately

Comment: The toggle() event was removed in jQuery 1.9 http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the .click() function instead, toggle is used to switch visibility on/off

"With no parameters, the .toggle() method simply toggles the visibility of elements" ([link to doc](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)).

And you don't really need the $(document.ready) unless you are loading scripts after the `</body>` tag ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438883/jquery-why-use-document-ready-if-external-js-at-bottom-of-page))

```
$("h2").click( function(){ 
   $(this).next().toggle(); 
});
```

EDIT : Depending on your jQuery version, behaviour might change

EDIT 2 : to start hidden, just add

```
$("h2").next().hide();
```

Or give it a class/id, and in your CSS stylesheet add

```
#yourId {
    visiblity: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much,is there a way I can make it start as hidden?

Comment: I am using jquery 1.11.1, toggle(false); doesn't work,I'll go with css,thanks for all that info,I'll choose your answer when possible.

Comment: Sorry, i edited it just after to replace by "hide()", which is what you originally did  ^^"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.click()` to add an onclick handler to your `<h2>`, which toggles the display of the next element. Try this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h2").click(function(){ 
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Clickable Title</h2>
<p>Toggle text</p>
```