# How to use jQuery sooner, if its loaded at the bottom of page?

Tags: jquery, html

ok, lets load jQuery at the bottom. But I need it sooner than that:

```
<body>
<div id="aaaa"></div>
<script>
  $('#aaa').click FAIL
</script>
</body>
<script src=jquery>
```

Comment: Then load it as the first script in the `<head></head>` section?

Comment: Then load it in the head of the document..?

Comment: Seems a bit over the top to ask this trivial question twice within half an hour. You simply can't use jQuery before it's loaded. And there's always vanilla JS as an option. http://stackoverflow.com/q/33417000/3168107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if some people don't recommend it, I do recommend loading jQuery as the first script in your website. The jQuery plugins and stuff can go at the bottom of your document without problems if you add non-intrusive code **after** loading them.

Instead of loading at the bottom of the `<body></body>` part of the document, load it in the header:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_file.js"></script>
        <!-- ... -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- ... -->
        <a href="#" id="aaa">Click me</a>
        <!-- ... -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#aaa').click(function(e) { alert('Now this should work.'); });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As a sidenote, please consider not including any script inside the `<body>` tag. jQuery is made to be, as I said before, **non-intrusive**, meaning it should not be mixed with the HTML. You're doing bad practices.

Your `$('#aaa').click` could (and should) be called in a script outside of the `body` tag itself and after importing jQuery. You could perfectly include that `script` tag just below the one that imports the jQuery library and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

`(function(){click Event here});`
Last step jQuery append as Last Element for the Body for faster loading

Extern scripts for more performance und er the jquery Core

Answer (score 1):

Either move the jquery tag up, or put the other script tag also below under where you include jquery